# parsing xml via linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, iteration

I've been tring to figure out a good way to parse the following kind of XML to arrive at a collection of objects as shown below the XML. Mind you, the whole set up is going to be dynamic and the schema of the incoming xml could change. The resulting object will *not* change! For that reason I am also creating a mapping xml that I'm going to use to parse out the incoming xml.

Here is a small example of a data xml. There will be a large number (20-30) of 'testrecords' and different data types aside from <DATASET>.

```
<TESTREPORT>
<DATASET>
    <TESTRECORD>
      <ID_SOURCE>Common Value A</ID_SOURCE>
      <TESTDATA>
        <TEST_NAME>Record Number</TEST_NAME>
        <TEST_VALUE>12345</TEST_VALUE>
      </TESTDATA>
      <TESTDATA>
        <TEST_NAME>Software Part Number</TEST_NAME>
        <TEST_VALUE>111111</TEST_VALUE>
      </TESTDATA>
    </TESTRECORD> 
    <TESTRECORD>
      <ID_SOURCE>Common Value B</ID_SOURCE>
      <TESTDATA>
        <TEST_NAME>Record Number</TEST_NAME>
        <TEST_VALUE>23456</TEST_VALUE>
      </TESTDATA>
      <TESTDATA>
        <TEST_NAME>Unit Checksum</TEST_NAME>
        <TEST_VALUE>ABCDEF23</TEST_VALUE>
      </TESTDATA>
    </TESTRECORD> 
</DATASET>
```

Here's a first draft of the mapping XML I'm envisioning. The problem I'm currently having is how to get the <ID_SOURCE>-value to "stick" as I iterate through the <TESTDATA> elements using LINQ to XML.

```
<segment code="TEST" segmentid="2">
<datadetails>
    <datadetail path="REPORT/DATASET/TESTRECORD">
        <datapoint name="Source" path="ID_SOURCE" sticky="??" />
        <datapoint name="Data" path="TESTDATA/TEST_NAME" />
        <datapoint name="Value" path="TESTDATA/TEST_VALUE" />
    </datadetail>
</datadetails>
```

Here is the object (or series of them) I need to create:

```
new Detail { Source = "Common Value A", Data = "Record Number", Value = "12345" };
new Detail { Source = "Common Value A", Data = "Software Part Number", Value = "111111" };
new Detail { Source = "Common Value B", Data = "Record Number", Value = "23456" };
new Detail { Source = "Common Value B", Data = "Unit Checksum", Value = "ABCDEF23" };
```

I just threw out my n-th approach and am looking for input. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: one thing to add: I'm using the excellent LINQPad to prototype this and, therefore, don't have any code to share as I haven't saved anything worthwhile...

Comment: "the schema of the incoming xml could change" - could it change *at runtime* ? IMO that would be the *only* reason for building an engine that can adjust the mapping dynamically. If you are always going to find out about changes in sufficient time to *write code*, then @Anthony Pegram's answer demonstrates just how straightforward the code will be. Far better (again IMO) to have to edit C# than some xml-based system which will over time approach being a Turing-complete language anyway - except one that's much much harder to maintain...

Comment: @AakashM - Your point is well taken. Though, the vendor ships updates to their software every 3 weeks (!) which could result in schema changes to the incoming XML any time. While not likely it would be a maintenance nightmare having to re-deploy new code for even minor changes every three weeks. Plus, due to the way the users will send us the data through the vendor's software we will have to support multiple versions of the xml schema. I know we have to strike a balance but this is a relatively important "feature."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var results = from testRecord in xdocument.Descendants("TESTRECORD")
              let source = testRecord.Element("ID_SOURCE").Value
              from testData in testRecord.Elements("TESTDATA")
              select new Detail
              {
                  Source = source,
                  Data = testData.Element("TEST_NAME").Value,
                  Value = testData.Element("TEST_VALUE").Value
              };
```

It's basically a `SelectMany` over your XML, extracting the common ID_SOURCE for each TESTRECORD element and applying that to the inner TESTDATA elements, producing a single `IEnumerable<Detail>` (assuming you've defined that class).

Comment: Anthony, that's awesome! Thanks so much!
Now, in order to make this dynamic and dependent on the mapping xml how would you approach that?

Comment: @austriacus, it really comes down to how dynamic is dynamic. If the XML format is truly unpredictable, you're going to have enough time coding to it. As it is, the code snippet conforms to your provided XML. Notice that it doesn't contain a single mention of DATASET, so it would also retrieve TESTRECORD elements contained inside FOO, BAR, etc.

Comment: it's not super dynamic. If the schema changes (it comes in from a vendor) we would know about it. But I'm trying my best to avoid any unnecessary code changes and have most changes be driven by the mapping xml.

Comment: @austriacus, well, it's an interesting problem. I'll admit to skimming over the mapping XML bit prior to writing an answer, so I didn't address that part. If I have time later, I'll come back to it.